# Post service in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-services, restangular

I would like to write login service in `Angular 2` and I use `restangular`. It's my service :

```
export class LoginService {

constructor(private restangular: Restangular) {
}

getAuthenticate(name : string, password: string) {
 return this.restangular
  .all('authenticate')
  .post({name: name, password: password});


  }
}
```

In my Login Component I import my login service and when I tried use him like this:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

user : any = {};

constructor(private loginService : LoginService) { }

ngOnInit() { 
}

login(){
  this.loginService.getAuthenticate(this.user.name, this.user.password)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  }

}
```

Have error

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./LoginComponent class LoginComponent - inline template:15:10 caused by: this.loginService.getAuthenticate is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolve this error. Forgot add

```
providers: [LoginService]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create servicehubpoint class as common access point and you can export the class so that where needed you can import the servicehubpoint in service also definitely you needed to use "providers" to includes all the services in the component.